# Dispatching JS Event from Deep Nested iFrame to Multiple Parent Windows

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events

Let's say there is page A, that has an iframe that contains page B and page B includes another iframe containing page C.

Can an event be fired from page C in a way that it traverses upwards and is received by both pages A and B?

Basically, is there a solution other than going to parent windows one by one and calling `contentWindow.postMessage` on each one? Is there a more concise way?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this so both page will be a part of single DOM

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#B').load("B.html");
      $('#C').load("C.html");

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class='parent'>
    <div id="A"></div>
    <div id="B"></div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```